# Is there a way to do both this functions at once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I have created an animation for a theme park. My goal is to let the user decide the total amount of tickets they want. For example if they've selected the button with "two persons" two carts ride across the screen. Then a hidden button shows up that redirects them to a new html page where they can pay two tickets. [Here is the html page I have at the moment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKbTg.png)

First off, this is my html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Beginscene</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/karretjestest.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<body>

<img id="rideeen" src="C:\Users\marin\Documents\avans\leerjaar2\Blok 7\PROG\ride.png">

<div class="allebuttons">
  <button class="buttons" TYPE="BUTTON" id="editeen" onclick="changeImage();"><div class="myDIV">1 person</div></button>
    <div><a href="C:\Users\marin\Documents\avans\leerjaar2\Blok 7\PROG\uitwerking\eenpersoon.html"><INPUT class="buttons" TYPE="BUTTON" id="saveeen"></a></div>


    <button class="buttons" TYPE="BUTTON" id="edittwee" onclick="changeImagetwee();"><div class="myDIV">2 persons</div></button>
    <div><a href="C:\Users\marin\Documents\avans\leerjaar2\Blok 7\PROG\uitwerking\tweepersonen.html"><INPUT class="buttons" TYPE="BUTTON" id="savetwee"></a></div>


    <button class="buttons" TYPE="BUTTON" id="editdrie" onclick="changeImagedrie();"><div class="myDIV">3 persons</div></button>
    <div><a href="C:\Users\marin\Documents\avans\leerjaar2\Blok 7\PROG\uitwerking\driepersonen.html"><INPUT class="buttons" TYPE="BUTTON" id="savedrie"></a></div>


    <button class="buttons" TYPE="BUTTON" id="editvier" onclick="changeImagevier();"><div class="myDIV">4 persons</div></button>
    <div><a href="C:\Users\marin\Documents\avans\leerjaar2\Blok 7\PROG\uitwerking\vierpersonen.html"><INPUT class="buttons" TYPE="BUTTON" id="savevier"></a></div>

    </div>


<script src="js/attractie.js"></script>
<script src="js/buttons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I've got two different Javascript files. The first one contains the following:

```js
function changeImage()
{
var img = document.getElementById("rideeen");
img.src="C:/Users/marin/Documents/avans/leerjaar2/Blok 7/PROG/ride.png";
return false;
}

function changeImagetwee()
{
var img = document.getElementById("rideeen");
img.src="C:/Users/marin/Documents/avans/leerjaar2/Blok 7/PROG/ridetwee.png";
return false;
}

function changeImagedrie()
{
var img = document.getElementById("rideeen");
img.src="C:/Users/marin/Documents/avans/leerjaar2/Blok 7/PROG/ridedrie.png";
return false;
}

function changeImagevier()
{
var img = document.getElementById("rideeen");
img.src="C:/Users/marin/Documents/avans/leerjaar2/Blok 7/PROG/ridevier.png";
return false;
}
```

The second file looks like this:

```js
var editeen = document.getElementById("editeen");
var saveeen = document.getElementById("saveeen");
var edittwee = document.getElementById("edittwee");
var savetwee = document.getElementById("savetwee");
var editdrie = document.getElementById("editdrie");
var savedrie = document.getElementById("savedrie");
var editvier = document.getElementById("editvier");
var savevier = document.getElementById("savevier");

editeen.onclick = function() {
    saveeen.style.visibility = "visible";

}
edittwee.onclick = function() {
    savetwee.style.visibility = "visible";

  }
  editdrie.onclick = function() {
      savedrie.style.visibility = "visible";

    }

    editvier.onclick = function() {
        savevier.style.visibility = "visible";

      }
```

I've come across the problem that there seem to be only two options:
1: When the buttons with text are clicked the ride is changing to another amount of rides, but the hidden buttons don't work.
2: When the buttons with text are clicked the ride doesn't change, but the hidden buttons work.

Does anyone have a solution for this?
All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

- if you wants to change the source of the image then show the link button it's will look like this

```
var double = document.getElementById("editeen");
var img = document.getElementById("rideeen");
var inp = document.getElementById("saveeen");
double.addEventListener("click", function () { 
    img.src = "/path/image.png";
    inp.style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

- or you can send them directly without clicking another button by location

```
var double = document.getElementById("editeen");
var img = document.getElementById("rideeen");
var inp = document.getElementById("saveeen");
double.addEventListener("click", function () { 
    img.src = "/path/image.png";
    window.location.href = "https://example.com/";
});
```